# An issue for Data binding at datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, page-lifecycle

Actually, say problem to that maybe wrong. I have 2 page. I can get the query string at second page from first page. And this query string is my critical part of query. When debug mode, i can see the result of query and they would be what i want. but it cannot be shown on my gridview. 
Here is my code block:
my CustomerList page,

```
public partial class CustomerList : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        CustomerBusiness m_CustomerBusiness = new CustomerBusiness();
        COMPANY m_Company = new COMPANY();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    BindCustomers();
                }
            }

        private void BindCustomers()
                {
                    string CompanyName = Request.QueryString.Get("CompanyName");

                    LabelCompanyName.Text = CompanyName;
                    List<CUSTOMER> CustomerListt = m_CustomerBusiness.SelectByFirmName(CompanyName);
                    GridViewCustomerList.DataSource = CustomerListt;
                    GridViewCustomerList.DataBind();
                }
}
```

GridViewCustomerList:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewCustomerList" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" 
            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" 
            ondatabinding="GridViewCustomerList_DataBinding" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridViewCustomerList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            Width="239px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

CustomerList is as what i want but my bind part doesn't work, i cannot see the GridViewCustomerList when i run the project. I research something asp.net page life-cycle model, the target solution maybe related with that.

Comment: Can you show the markup for your `GridView`?

Comment: If i could see that, i would show it.. But as i said, i could see the result of query on debug mode..

Comment: Sorry, I'm referring to the markup for `GridViewCustomerList`, as it appears on your ASPX page (in Visual Studio).  Please add *that* to your question.

Comment: No problem, but I think you are still misunderstanding me =)  In your ASPX page, I want to see your `GridView` declaration.  It should start with something like this: `<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridViewCustomerList">`.  Then use the [edit] button to add that content to your question.

Comment: i noticed to still missunderstand you and delete my comment before you =) Ok. i added it.

Comment: I follow you now, thanks for adding that!  I think I see what the problem is, I've posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you have no explicit [`<Column>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx) declarations in your markup, and you have [`AutoGenerateColumns` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) set to "false".  Thus, even though the data gets bound to your GridView control, it doesn't know what to display (so it displays nothing.

The easiest solution here is to just removed `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` from your GridView declaration (it is "true" by default), and you should be good to go.  It will automatically create your columns based on your DataSource.

Alternately, you can specify which columns you want by adding a columns section to your GridView.

```
    <columns>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="columnOne" headertext="Column 1"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="columnTwo" headertext="Column 2"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="columnThree" headertext="Column 3"/>
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: thank you so much @jadarnel27. still i can not believe the problem's solution is only changing 'false' =)

Comment: @yiddow Sometimes it's just that easy =)